# type operator return value for null

Tags: javascript

I have found a strange behavior for the type operator return value. Take a look at the following code:

[image: null result]

So I obtain **object** as the type of null using typeof operator. Is that a browser related bug or is it the expected behaviour? It does not sound normal to me that typeof would return "object" for a null value. I would expect null instead. I have tested on chrome. Thanks

Comment: couple of duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+typeof+null+object

Comment: for more details please refer to http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:typeof_null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) this is a bug in ECMAScript, should be null.

> In the first implementation of JavaScript, JavaScript values were
>   represented as a type tag and a value. The type tag for objects was 0.
>   null was represented as the NULL pointer (0x00 in most platforms).
>   Consequently, null had 0 as type tag, hence the bogus typeof return
>   value. (

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: thanks... I have reached my daily voting limit. Will up vote tomorrow...

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior, as defined in [the ES5 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) at [section 11.4.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3):

> 3. Return a String determined by Type(val) according to Table 20.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> Type of val   Result
> Null          "object"
> ```

The `typeof` operator is never defined to return `'null'` for any value, regardless of whether it's actually null or not. It does handle `undefined` as you might expect, but they chose not to treat null specially.